# How does uWSGI compare with mod_wsgi today?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, uwsgi, wsgi

I've not done Python programming for more than a decade now and the mod_wsgi Apache module used to be one of the best WSGI server at that time. Since then many other WSGI servers seem to have cropped up, out of which uWSGI seems to be a popular and decent project. Some things I am curious about include:

1. Is uWSGI as stable and production-ready as mod_wsgi?
2. Is uWSGI as [strict about the WSGI specification](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/requirements.html) as mod_wsgi?
3. How do the two otherwise compare on feature set and performance?

Answer (score 0):

[Graham Dumpleton (creator of mod_wsgi)'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820302/4115031) to ["Compare nginx+Apache+mod_wsgi vs nginx+uWSGI?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819607/compare-nginxapachemod-wsgi-vs-nginxuwsgi) seems relevant:

> When you load your typical large Python web application on top of the
> most popular WSGI servers, **the performance difference isn't actually
> that much** and usually nothing to get excited about. Hello world
> benchmarks like the one you quote are very misleading as they test a
> very narrow use case and the configurations used are usually never
> comparable. You should consider watching my PyCon talk which talk
> about bottlenecks in web servers and web applications.
>
> http://pyvideo.org/video/703/web-server-bottlenecks-and-performance-tuning
>
> Given that the WSGI server is not usually the problem, you should **just
> choose that which you find easiest to manage and has the sorts of
> features you think you will require**. Then use benchmarking and
> monitoring of that choice to work out how to set it up so as to
> perform best for your specific web application. Even then, any
> increase in performance or gains in user satisfaction are not usually
> going to come from such tuning.

Comment: I had read that, but that answer is more a comparison or statement on webservers (Apache vs Nginx) where as I want to know about mod_wsgi vs uwsgi (code quality, standard compliance, features, performance etc).

Comment: It seems like Graham's answer would be something like "they're both fine, their particular performance will depend on your specific use-case; if you need a specific feature, check which one has what you need".

Comment: I can trust mod_Wsgi because of @GrahamDumpleton and because I have used it in production. I know nothing about the uwsgi project, expect that it seems popular today, and hence the research and request for advise.